# If external file doesn't exist file is stopped: is possible to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, null, undefined

Sorry for title but is difficult to explain this...
I have external javascript file with inside there's a variable (`var eui`)

My code is run if this variable exist and if is not exist alert something.

```
    if((eui != 000) || (eui !== null) || (typeof eui !== 'undefined')){ 
     alert('ok');
    }
    else{
     alert('not exist file');
    }
```

In my case, with console, i read that `eui is not defined` and second alert is not print.

Why ?
How can i solve this?

Comment: external js file may not be getting loaded

Comment: yes and how can i solve this ? how can i add in the IF that file could not loaded ?

Comment: your 'if' stament makes little sence - you need to understand order of precedence.   check for undefined first

Comment: first `if` will check conditions inside with the same order, so you want to check first if the variable exists and then the rest of conditions, second you should use `&&` and not `||` .. try this `if( (typeof eui !== 'undefined') && (eui != 000) && (eui !== null) ) { }`

Comment: show that where are you adding js tag so anyone can get an idea

Comment: Same idea @AmaniBenAzzouz :)

Comment: yeah :D .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your condition in if-statement is incorrect. I think this one might work better:

```
if ((typeof eui !== 'undefined') && (eui !== null) && (eui != 000)) {
  alert('ok');
} else {
  alert('not exist file');
}
```

So you first need to check if `eui` is properly defined and proceed with other checks only if it's true. It means that you want to use `&&` operators (AND condition, not OR).

Comment: now work... i did not know that is important the order and for this reason i used OR operators. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is how `||` works. You have `a || b || c`. Because it's OR, it means that if `a` evaluates to `true`, `b` and `c` are not even going to be checked, `a` being `true` is enough. With `&&` everything will need to be checked in order for result to be `true`. That's why you first check that there is such variable `eui` at all, and if so, you can continue with other checks reliably. If `eui` is `undefined`, then `typeof eui !== 'undefined'` is `false` and other conditions are not relevant and skipped.